# Getting error when installing expo by using this command (npm install expo-cli --global)

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

[image]

Unable to install expo globally using this command npm install expo-cli --global during installation i face these following errors. Any one please give me suggestions to solve this problem.

Comment: Did you try delete existing file which mentioned in the error and reinstall it?

Comment: yes i also re install node js even npm and node-modules...